# Mongodb user schema error

Tags: mongodb, express, mean-stack

I am trying to use postman to send data thru and create my user. but I keep getting an error so I commented out some code that really isn't needed and now I am getting this error. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

[image: Problem with mongo]

[image: Bottom of user code]

Mongodb is connected and the server is running on port 3000.

Comment: The error appears to be complaining about a variable being undefined around line 63 in user.js.  Have you considered using console.log to output each variable at that point to see what each variable contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2282634/joe) and [@robertklep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893780/robertklep) already mentioned you have your error in line 63:

> bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash => {

because variable **password** is **undefined**.
Try to define it manually and make the sure that code, what you have written executed correctly.

But I highly recommend you to take a close look [at virtual field (in mongoose)](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) and use it for generating salt passwords.

In your case you could do the same job with this code snippet using mongoose and bcrypt.

//first of all, rename "password" to "clean_password" in your schema

```
user.virtual('clean_password')
    .set(function(clean_password) {
        this._password = clean_password;
        this.password = this.encryptPassword(clean_password);
    })
    .get(function() {
        return this._password;
    });

user.methods = {

    /**
     * Authenticate - check if the passwords are the same
     *
     * @param {String} plainText
     */
    authenticate: function(plainPassword) {
        return bcrypt.compareSync(plainPassword, this.password);
    },

    /**
     * Encrypt password
     *
     * @param {String} password
     */
    encryptPassword: function(password) {
        if (!password)
            return '';

        return bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10);
    }
};
```

and check it via:

```
var user = {
    username: "whateveryouwant",
    clean_password: "whateveryouneed"
}

User.create(user, function(err,doc){});
```

Answer (score 1):

The error states that you're passing an invalid argument to `bcrypt.hash()`, namely `undefined` instead of a password. Check if `req.body.password` is defined.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure making a console.log(newUser) before catching the newUser.password in addUser function. The object is not coming as you are expecting after initiating a new User schema with data. or simmply give a string from your own to make a salt pass then check if it is working properly.